# Put description on picture in Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

How can I put a image description right under the picture at the Lightbox?

I use this Lightbox plugin:
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: I that script just put it in title of "a" tag.

Answer (score 1):

The description is taken from the title attribute of the a tag. Like

```
<a href="image.jpg" title="Example image">
      <img src="thumb_image.jpg">
</a>
```

So your description will be **Example image**.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the title bar like so:

```
<a href="img.jpg" title="enter a title here">
    <img src="thumb_img.jpg" alt="no image title here" />
</a>
```

This will be fully W3 certified. alt = alternate text for an image.